# Do Hermite polynomials exist for negative integers?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, error-function, hermite-polynomials

I recently asked a question about a differential equation, and received [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237761/problem-with-2nd-order-differential-equation/2237856#2237856) as an answer. It included a Hermite polynomial of negative degree, namely $H_{-3}$. I searched online and it seems as though these $H_n$'s are only defined for $n\ge0$, and for $n<0$ something else might used - *parabolic cylinder functions*. I say 'might' because I am not sure if they are actually the same. I have never heard of these, and so was hoping someone would know about them here. Can they be expressed in terms of *erf* or *erfc*? I found another link which suggested they could. If so, how?

To clarify I want to know if Hermite polynomials (or their equivalent) can be expressed for negative integers $n$ in some closed form expression (including *erf*).

Comment: Hermite polynomials satisfy a two-step recurrence relation, and that can be used to product the ones with negative index.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Is this $H_{n+1}(x)=2xH_n(x)-2nH_{n-1}(x)$? If so, due to the $n$ multiplying the final term, isn't some other method needed to find $H_{-1}(x)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*As I added to my answer to the previous question.*

Expanded using more usual functions, $$H_{-3}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{16} \left(\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{x^2}{4}} \left(x^2+2\right)
   \text{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-2 x\right)$$

Similarly,$$H_{-1}\left({x}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } e^{x^2} \text{erfc}(x)$$ $$H_{-2}\left({x}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{\pi } e^{x^2} x \text{erfc}(x)\right)$$ $$H_{-3}\left({x}\right)=\frac{1}{8} \left(\sqrt{\pi } e^{x^2} \left(2 x^2+1\right) \text{erfc}(x)-2 x\right)$$ $$H_{-4}\left({x}\right)=\frac{1}{24} \left(2 \left(x^2+1\right)-\sqrt{\pi } e^{x^2} x \left(2 x^2+3\right)
   \text{erfc}(x)\right)$$ $$H_{-5}\left({x}\right)=\frac{1}{192} \left(\sqrt{\pi } e^{x^2} \left(4 \left(x^2+3\right) x^2+3\right)
   \text{erfc}(x)-2 x \left(2 x^2+5\right)\right)$$

Comment: I'm willing to go along with this because I can see that $H_{−1}$ is the differintegration of the $H_n(x)$ just below. However, I have to ask, just where did you get H_{−3} to begin the recursion?

Answer (score 5):

After two days of thinking about this, I see now how Hermite polynomials can be extended to negative indices from a more basic approach. I was inspired to do this because you can't argue with Claude's result. So let's return to the Rodriques formula,

$$\text{H}_n(x)=(-)^n e^{x^2} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$$

Thinking in terms of fractional calculus, I'm going to stretch the imagination and allow for differintegration with negative $n$. Thus we boldly say that

$$\text{H}_{-1}(x)=-e^{x^2} \int e^{-x^2} dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{x^2}\text{erfx}(x)$$

This is in agreement with Claude's result. At this point we can continue with the recursion formula since we know that $H_0=1$. Thus, working down the negative numbers,

$$\text{H}_n(x)=\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\left[2\text{H}_{n+1}(x)-\text{H}_{n+2}(x)\right],\ \ \ \ n<-1$$

Obviously, these are not *polynomials*, but they derive from the Hermite polynomial recursion so that's what we call it. These look much different than the *regular* Hermite polynomials.

The figure below show the first eight $H_n, n\le -1$. Notice the logarithmic $y$-axis.
[image: Negative Hermite Polynomials]

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, Ch. 24, Springer, and I see no mention of negative $n$ for the Hermite polynomials. Moreover, a Rodrigues's formula seems to rule it out altogether,

$$\text{H}_n(x)=(-)^ne^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$$

On the other hand, the integral representation does not seem so prejudiced,

$$\text{H}_n(x)=\frac{2^{n+1}e^{x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}t^ne^{-t^2}cos\left(2xt-\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)dt$$

But again, there is no mention of negative $n$ in that chapter. In addition is stated clearly that the Hermite polynomials are a special case of the parabolic cylinder function, whose order $\nu$ is a **nonnegative integer** $n$ and is given by

$$\text{D}_n(x)=2^{-n/2}e^{-x^2/4}\text{H}_n\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

I don't see any reference to the error function.

UPDATE: I found the following relation with respect to the error function in Olver, *et al.*, *NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions*,

$$\frac{d^{n+1}\text{erf}\ z}{dz^n}=(-1)^n\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\text{H}_n(z) e^{-z^2}, \ \ \ \ n=0,1,2,\ ...$$

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks. Now I just wonder what Claude Leibovici meant in his answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Take $n \in {\mathbb N}$ and $n \ge 1$. By generalizing the Rodrigues's formula to negative values of $n$ we write:

\begin{eqnarray}
    &&H_{-n}(x) := (-1)^{n+1} e^{x^2} \cdot \int\limits_x^\infty \frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} e^{-t^2} dt \\
    &&= \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} 
    \sum\limits_{m=0}^{\lfloor \frac{j}{2} \rfloor}
    \binom{n-1}{j} x^{n-1-j} (-1)^j (\frac{j-1}{2})_{(m)} \left( \right. \\
    && \left.
    x^{j-1-2 m} 1_{m < \lfloor \frac{j}{2} \rfloor} + 
    [1 \cdot 1_{j\%2=1} + \sqrt{\pi} e^{x^2} \mbox{erfc}(x) 1_{j\%2=0}] 1_{m = \lfloor \frac{j}{2} \rfloor} \right. \\
    && \left.
    \right) \\
&&=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2(n-1)!}\underline{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-2}{2} \rfloor} \left(j!\sum\limits_{m=2j+1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{m} (-1)^m \binom{\frac{m-1}{2}}{j}\right) x^{n-2-2j}} + \\
&&\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2(n-1)!}\underline{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor} \binom{n-1}{2 j} \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^{(j)} x^{n-1-2 j} }\cdot \sqrt{\pi} e^{x^2} \mbox{erfc}(x)
    \end{eqnarray}
where $j_{(m)} := j(j-1)\cdots(j-m+1)$ is the lower Pochhammer symbol.

```
In[243]:= x =.; mm = 20;
Table[(-1)^(n - 1)/(n - 1)! 1/2 Sum[
      Binomial[n - 1, j] x^(n - 1 - j) (-1)^
        j Pochhammer[(j - 1)/2 - m + 1, m] If[m < Floor[j/2], 
        x^(j - 1 - 2 m), 
        If[Mod[j, 2] == 1, 1, Sqrt[\[Pi]] E^x^2 Erfc[x]]], {j, 0, 
       n - 1}, {m, 0, Floor[j/2]}] - HermiteH[-n, x], {n, 1, mm}] // 
  FunctionExpand // Simplify
Table[ (-1)^(-1 + n)/(2 (-1 + n)!)
      Sum[(Sum[
          Binomial[n - 1, m] (-1)^m Binomial[(m - 1)/2, j], {m, 
           2 j + 1, n - 1}] j!) x^(n - 2 - 2 j), {j, 0, 
       Floor[(n - 2)/2]}] + (-1)^(-1 + n)/(2 (-1 + n)!)
      Sum[Binomial[n - 1, 2 j + 0]  Pochhammer[1/2, 
        j] x^(n - 1 - 2 j) , {j, 0, Floor[(n - 1)/2]}] Sqrt[\[Pi]] E^
      x^2 Erfc[x] +
    -HermiteH[-n, x]
   , {n, 1, mm}] // FunctionExpand // Simplify

Out[244]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Out[245]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

It turns out that those quantities appear in a natural way in stochastic processes, in the formula for the probability density function of the first hitting time of a certain diffusion process, as demonstrated [in my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588538/how-do-we-use-contour-integration-to-invert-a-laplace-transform/4626462#4626462).

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is wrong with my answer?Why was it down-voted?