# Integral of a single Hermite polynomial

Tags: definite-integrals, hermite-polynomials

Is there a solution to this definite integral

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{d*} 
\left(\sqrt{c_0\; x^2 +c_1}\right)^{-m} 
H_{-m}\left(c_2\; \sqrt{\frac{c_0\; x^2}{c_0\; x^2 + c_1}}\right)
\mathrm{d} x 
$$

with $m$ a positive integer and $c_0$, $c_1$, and $c_2$ constants where $H$ is the Hermite polynomial?

I am using the physics version of the Hermite polynomial.

Comment: What is a Hermite polynomial with negative order?

Comment: $d$ is probably one of the worst choices of letter for a variable of integration.

Comment: I am sorry that the variable examined is known as $d$ in my research community (cognitive neurosciences). I'll send a request to rename it.

Comment: @Gary : One definition of Hermite polynomials are those that satisfy the differential equation $y''-2x y'+2n y=0$. Although the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) fails to mention it, nothing prevent $n$ from being negative. See this [SE response](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238662/do-hermite-polynomials-exist-for-negative-integers).

Comment: @DenisCousineau Yes, but then they are no longer polynomials. I changed your integration variable from $d$ to $x$. I hope you don't mind. Since we don't use the context here, I belive it does not matter.